# Socket Server - How can I get the name of the client in Log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, xml, sockets, logging, log4j2

I have a socket server set up to receive log events from multiple machines and multiple web applications. How can I retrieve the name of the client (preferably in the XML configuration) sending each event? Or am I entirely off-base on the best practice for separating logs in this framework?

---

Expected result: a socket server with a Log4j2 routing appender that can identify the client name of inbound log events and route it to the appropriate file accordingly.

Result I'm getting: Without the router, it writes all log events to all files redundantly. With the router, since I don't know the correct lookup, no events are logged to any file.

---

Modified version of one client's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Configuration status="trace">  
    <Appenders>  

        <Socket
            name="Socket"
            host="log4j-srv"
            port="1234"
        >
            <SerializedLayout />
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>  
    <Loggers>  
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Socket"/>
        </Root>  
    </Loggers>  
</Configuration>
```

And the server:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <Configuration status="trace">
        <Appenders>  
            <Routing name="Routing">
                <Routes pattern="???">
                    <Route>
                        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Default" 
                                                 fileName="example1.log" 
                                                 example-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                            <PatternLayout pattern="${hostName} %d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                            <Policies>
                                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                            </Policies>
                            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
                        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
                    </Route>
                    <Route key="client1">
                        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Client1" 
                                                 fileName="otherexample.log" 
filePattern="otherexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                            <PatternLayout pattern="${hostName} %d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
                            <Policies>
                                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                            </Policies>
                            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
                        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Routing>
        </Appenders>  
        <Loggers>  
            <Root level="info">  
                <AppenderRef ref="Routing"/>
            </Root>  
        </Loggers>  
    </Configuration>
```

Comment: Defne 'name of the client'.

Comment: @EJP as in the hostname of the sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the default configuration the SocketAppender does not include the host name of the sender. However, you can easily do this by doing:

```
<Logger name="com.acme" level="debug" additivity="false">
  <Property name="hostName">$${hostName}</Property>
  <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
</Logger>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! But how do I retrieve a Property in the Socket Server's configuration? Is it in the Thread Context Map?

Comment: -- Update: Never mind! It is indeed in the context map, I just had the syntax wrong. Should be $${ctx:hostName}, or whatever the property name is.